# remove currency symbol from itemprop="price", in prestashop 1.6

Tags: regex, prestashop, product, prestashop-1.6, breadcrumbs

product page:  https://www.cdsoft.co.il/index.php?id_product=301391&controller=product

the content of the itemprop="price" is presented with currency symbol : 118 ₪

```
<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="119" data-font-size="14" data-font-size-type="px">118 ₪‎</span>
```

I'm trying to reach to this:

```
<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="119" data-font-size="14" data-font-size-type="px">118 ₪‎</span>
```

in product.tpl :

```
<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="{ceil($productPrice|floatval)}">{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}</span>
```

I've tried to remove the symbol by adding regex:

```
<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="{ceil($productPrice|floatval)|regex_replace:'/ ₪/':' '}">{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}</span>
```

it didn't work.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

The Regex is looking for a forward slash followed by a space and then the currency symbol, rather than just the currency symbol, while forward slash (/) is being used as a delimiter to enclose the regular expression and as a special character to match the currency symbol (₪).

You can try a different delimiter, such as the tilde (~):

`<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="{ceil($productPrice|floatval)|regex_replace:'~ ₪~':' '}">{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}</span>`

or escape the forward slash:

`<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="{ceil($productPrice|floatval)|regex_replace:'/ \\\\₪/':' '}">{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}</span>`

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working ... any other solution?